# Creating pkg file with a option to user launch application after install

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, pkg-file

I am using Packages application to create the .pkg file for my Mac Os x application.
My requirement is to have a UI where user can check or uncheck wether he wants to launch application after installation is completed.

Currently I am using postflight.sh to launch the application after install

Please help

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have found the solution for this ... we need to create installer plugin and add that to over pkg installer